# Bookmarks in MVC web application with changing iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, iframe

In my CodeIgniter web application I am changing the src attribute of an iframe element each time the user clicks on a link in the navigation.

I managed to create a usable history via the history API of HTML 5 and now the URL is changing accordingly. But because these URL don't actually point to places in my application that actually exists I get a 404 error whenever I refresh the page in the browser or when the user would bookmark that page and would revisit it at a later time.

Now I would like to know how I can make my application with these URLs bookmarkable.

Here is the code when a user clicks on a navigation node:

```
$(document).on('click', '.node', function(event) {
            var nodeName = $(this).text();

            $('.node').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            //Load Links
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url('ajax/loadLinks'); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {nodeName: nodeName},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.links').remove();
                    $('nav').append(data);
                }
            });

            $('html,body').css("background-color", "#3C5575");


            //History manipulation
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            var nodeId = $(this).attr('id'); 

            var stateObj = {
                url: href,
                nodeId: nodeId
            };

            changeIframeSrc(document.getElementById("iframe"), href);
            history.pushState(stateObj, nodeName, nodeName);
        });
```

Here is the popstate event:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
        //console.log(event.state); 
        changeIframeSrc(document.getElementById("iframe"), history.state.url);
        //$('#iframe').attr('src', event.state.url);
        $('.node').removeClass('active');
        $('#' + history.state.nodeId).addClass('active');
    });
```

And here is the function where I switch the src attribute of the iframe to prevent it from generating 2 history entries:

```
var changeIframeSrc = function(iframe, src) {
        var frame = iframe.cloneNode(false);
        frame.src = src;
        iframe.parentNode.replaceChild(frame, iframe);
    };
```

The

Comment: I think sharing a little code will make the problem clearer, but I'm guessing you'll need to specify the frame source based on a query string

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.